# undefined method 'to_slice' for IO::ARGF (compile-time type is IO+)

Tags: crystal-lang

I try to write AJAX uploaded image `data:image/gif;base64,R0lGOD...` into file via IO. Got strange exception

```
in src/controllers/product.cr:41: instantiating 'Base64:Module#decode(IO+, File)'
Base64.decode(photo_b64_io, file)
in /usr/share/crystal/src/base64.cr:173: undefined method 'to_slice' for IO::ARGF (compile-time type is IO+)
from_base64(data.to_slice) do |byte|
```

My code

```
  photo_b64_io = env.request.body.not_nil!
  photo_b64_io.gets(",") # seek to real data

  File.open(File.join(upload_path, file_path, file_id), "w") do |file|
    Base64.decode(photo_b64_io, file)
  end
```

How to improve?

Answer (score 1):

[`Base64.decode`](https://crystal-lang.org/api/0.27.0/Base64.html#decode%28data%2Cio%3AIO%29-instance-method) does not take an `IO` as first parameter, it takes something that responds to `to_slice`, so a `String` or a `Slice` usually.

You either have to read the entire IO into memory first before passing it to `Base64.decode`, using `IO#gets_to_end` (given it's base64 encoded data it should be safe to read into a `String`).

Or if you want to stay memory-efficient you should read in chunks of an multiple of 4 (since with base64 encoding every 3 original bytes are encoded into 4 bytes), using `IO#read` (ensure to loop until your chunk is full and handle the EOF case), and then decode each full chunk and write the result to a file before recycling your buffer for the next chunk.

Comment: thanks, yep `http/body.gets_to_end` works, but I would like to stay memory-efficient